# What is the proper word for relationship?

Tags: english-to-japanese, word-requests

What would be the correct way to say "restoration of a broken relationship"? 関係 seems a bit sterile in the line of this poem I'm writing. 関係 feels like I'm referring to the connection between two inanimate objects. Is there an alternately preferred verbiage for parent-child, spouses,  lovers,  or dating relationships?

Comment: Hi. How about 絆{きずな} instead of 関係{かんけい}?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

関係 safely refers to a relationship between two people as well as two inanimate things. It's perfectly fine to say 壊れた関係の修復 in daily writings. But if you want a more colorful word, 繋がり and 絆 ("bond") may be considered. [よりを戻す](https://jisho.org/word/%E7%B8%92%E3%82%8A%E3%82%92%E6%88%BB%E3%81%99) is a common idiom but it's usable only in contexts related to romance.